# Creating a New Instance causes a Crash in the Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, public

Hello StackOverFlow Community! I have an issue with a line of code in one of my android, java apps I am currently building.

During the starting of the app, I run (amongst other code) the following code which creates a new instance of another class. It then runs a method inside of the class which sets up a number of different things inside of the app. As it is a large amount of processing, its in another thread to keep the app running at a good speed. The method cannot be static as it uses context. Whenever I create a new instance of the class that contains the thread (Longer_Tasks Set_Up_Reference = new Longer_Tasks()), it crashes. I am wondering how I can fix the code as I appear to have a run time error somewhere!

```
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {       
            Longer_Tasks Set_Up_Reference = new Longer_Tasks();
            Set_Up_Reference.Variable_Set_Up();
        }
    }).start();
```

I have narrowed it down to this line via the debugger.

I apologize for the lack of information, the following is the constructor:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;

public class Longer_Tasks extends Activity
{
 ... Other Functions and Procedures ...

    public void Variable_Set_Up()
    {
        Profile_Load_Data_From_File();
        Profile_Load_Data_From_Server();
    }

.... Other Functions and Procedures ...
}
```

The following is the stack trace (I think):

```
08-11 22:10:08.347: D/WifiStateMachine(1018): handleMessage: E msg.what=131155
08-11 22:10:08.347: D/WifiStateMachine(1018): processMsg: ConnectedState
08-11 22:10:08.348: D/WifiStateMachine(1018): processMsg: L2ConnectedState
08-11 22:10:08.361: D/WifiStateMachine(1018): handleMessage: X
08-11 22:10:11.364: D/WifiStateMachine(1018): handleMessage: E msg.what=131155
08-11 22:10:11.364: D/WifiStateMachine(1018): processMsg: ConnectedState
08-11 22:10:11.366: D/WifiStateMachine(1018): processMsg: L2ConnectedState
08-11 22:10:11.383: D/WifiStateMachine(1018): handleMessage: X
08-11 22:10:11.970: W/dalvikvm(9227): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b33d40)
08-11 22:10:11.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9227): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-46755
08-11 22:10:11.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9227): Process: com.messenger_app, PID: 9227
08-11 22:10:11.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9227): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-11 22:10:11.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9227):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
08-11 22:10:11.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9227):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
08-11 22:10:11.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9227):     at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:773)
08-11 22:10:11.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9227):     at com.messenger_app.Longer_Tasks.<init>(Longer_Tasks.java:22)
08-11 22:10:11.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9227):     at com.messenger_app.Home_Screen$1.run(Home_Screen.java:53)
08-11 22:10:11.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9227):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-11 22:10:11.996: W/ActivityManager(1018):   Force finishing activity com.messenger_app/.Home_Screen
08-11 22:10:12.160: D/dalvikvm(1018): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 663K, 18% free 25966K/31436K, paused 151ms, total 151ms
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Impossible to answer this without seeing the `Longer_Tasks` constructor, the `Variable_Set_Up` method, and when and where this chunk of code is being called from.

Comment: And also, what the crash is. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Also, check out [Android's code style guidelines](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html), especially for naming variables.

Comment: I have added extra bits to my question! I will give it a read, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate an Activity outside the main thread.

First, never do UI stuff outside of the main thread. [There's an established pattern for communicating back to the main thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html).

Second, never manually instantiate an activity. [Use an Intent to start Activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

You may want to walk through the official training material and pick apart the samples that come with the Android SDK to get an idea of how Android applications work.